# git sparse checkout, "hoisting" the directories

Tags: git

I'm working in a large git repo with a very large tree, and the relevant subtree is very deep. For argument's sake let's call it `/foo/bar/baz/quux/java/spiffy/main/src/`

I can do a sparse checkout to some working copy; let's call it `/tmp/git/spiffy`. The problem is that when I do the checkout, I get `/tmp/git/spiffy/foo/bar/baz/quux/java/spiffy/main/src`.

Is there any way to tell git to checkout the subtree as the root of the working copy, so I get `/tmp/git/spiffy` instead of all those extra layers?